# The Nim Group is a group?

Tags: group-theory

Consider the following exercise.

Let the set $G = \{0, 1, 2, 3,  4, 5,  6, 7\}$. Suppose there is a group (Called The Nim Group) operation $\ast$ on $G$ that satisfies the following two conditions:

(a) $a\ast b \geq a + b$ for all $a, b \in G$,

(b) $a\ast  a = 0$ for all $a \in G$.

Construct the multiplication table for $G$.

The exercise I found him in a document but I have a doubt if indeed the set $ G $ with the operation defined as a group.

I have a doubt with this exercise. Building the table until I get the following

[image]

My question is not how to continue, as should repeat elements in rows (being $ G $ a group) then it must meet that $ 1 \ast 7 =  2$ but if this is true not satisfy the condition (b) $a\ast b \geq a + b $. I appreciate your support.

Comment: Are you sure (a) is supposed to be regular addition, which suffices to fill out the whole table?  I believe it should be bitwise XOR, in which case (b) is satisfied but redundant.  I don't see how (b) gives you $a*b \ge a+b$-we don't have any order on this group.

Comment: With your new condition (a), how can $6 * 7 \ge 13$?

Comment: The group operation in NIM is usually defined recursively as follows
$$
a*b=\operatorname{mex}\left(\{a'*b\mid a'<a\}\cup \{a*b'\mid b'<b\}\right).
$$
Here $\operatorname{mex}(S)$ is defined for all proper subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ and means the smallest non-negative integer not in the set $S$ (=Minimum EXcluded number). So $0*0=0$ simply because both sets on the r.h.s. are empty. But then $0*1=\operatorname{mex}(\{0\})=1=1*0$, $1*1=\operatorname{mex}(\{1\})=0$,
$0*2=\operatorname{mex}(\{0,1\})=2=2*0$, $1*2=3$, $2*2=0$ et cetera.

Comment: And $\{0,1,2,3\}$ is also a group with respect to NIM addition, so your table should have $2*3=1$.

Comment: Jyrki Then I defined the group is not really a group?

Comment: Can you name/link the document you found this in?

Comment: @RoinerSeguraCubero I think (a) should be $a*b\leq a+b$

Answer (score 1):

As I'm holding the book "Contemporary Abstract Algebra" of Joseph A.Gallian 2nd edition, on exercise 27 of chapter 3, I looked up for the Nim Group, then I found your question.

So the question in the book is exactly the same as you wrote, but instead of your first condition, the condition in the exercise is $a*b\leq a+b$, which makes more sense as you pointed out.

So I think your document has a typo.